# Can you get a Device Context from a Bitmap?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to workout how to resize an image *after* I've converted it to a bitmap. From the `MSDN` examples, I was able to figure out how to resize *from* a DC (before it's converted to a bitmap)

```
# Big snapshot of the desktop
hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

zhwndDevice = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
zmfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(zhwndDevice)
zsaveDC = zmfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
zsaveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
zsaveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(zmfcDC, width, height)
zsaveDC.SelectObject(zsaveBitMap)
zsaveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), zmfcDC, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

# Creates a smaller bitmap and resizes the first image to fit it 
hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
hwndDevice = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
mfcDC   = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDevice)
saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, target_size[0], target_size[1])
saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)
win32gui.StretchBlt(pywintypes.HANDLE(saveDC.GetHandleAttrib()), 0,0,target_size[0], target_size[1], zsaveDC.GetHandleAttrib(), 0,0,width, height, win32con.SRCCOPY)
```

My question is, if I already have a Bitmap object, how would I go about creating a DC from it so that I can pass it to the `StretchBlt` method?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a Device Context is that it's a context suitable for some kind of device—your monitor, a printer, whatever. So, creating a DC for a bitmap doesn't make any sense. Read [Device Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more detail.

If you want to create an in-memory device context that's compatible with the current screen, that's exactly what you get from calling [`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `NULL` (from Python, `None` or `0`, depending on which wrapper you're using) as the `hdc` parameter:

> A handle to an existing DC. If this handle is NULL, the function creates a memory DC compatible with the application's current screen.

However, in your case, you're ultimately trying to blit this into a target window (or some other target) for which you already have a DC, right? So I think what you really want is to create a memory DC compatible with the *target* DC, then create a bitmap compatible with that target DC, then select that bitmap into the memory DC.